# Javascript problems in Firefox 3.5.7?

Tags: support, javascript, firefox

Is it just me, or is SO having Javascript problems in Firefox 3.5.7?

I can't add any comments, nor vote.

From the console:

```
 Error: editorReady is not defined
 Source: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2089031/edit
 Line: 97
```

-

```
Error: vote is not defined
Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089012/recommended-commenting-tool-add-in-for-visual-studio/2089031#2089031
Line: 49
```

works fine in Chrome. This started some 15 Minutes ago. I did't change anything on my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear your cache, do a forced reload and try it again.

Comment: That did the trick. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> is SO having Javascript problems in
>   Firefox 3.5.7?

No, I use Firefox 3.5.7 for SO sites and have had no problem.

Comment: I don't see why this deserves a downvote? +1 to even it out.

Comment: @Pekka, I can always count on Rich B(Geoffrey Chetwood) for a downvote.  I get a few from him each day.

Comment: he's not singling you out. RichB downvotes *everyone* all the time. I've seen the detailed stats, and rest assured, our beloved RichB is an equal opportunity downvoter..